# How correct to parse following JSON document including array

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe5

JSON-Document:

```
{"asks":
    [["0.01129999",0.9997237],["0.01130000",594.26412711],["0.01130826",0.23004724],["0.01130999",0.25231793]],
 "bids":
    [["0.01129800",174.30861783],["0.01128867",0.13287659],["0.01128817",0.0097447],["0.01127559",241.94881004]],
 "isFrozen":"0","seq":254407265
}
```

This is my first expirience of work with JSON-documents. I'm done that as I may. It work. But I think that it was wrong way. Because in my realization absent TJSONPair class, unlike many examples in net. Is there other variant of realisation comprising TJSONPair in my case?

```
const
  ArrString : array[0..1] of String = ('asks','bids');
var
  JSONObject: TJSONObject;
  JSONArray: TJSONArray;
  i,j: integer;
...

  JSONObject:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONString) as TJSONObject;
  if Assigned(JSONObject) then
    begin
    for i := 0 to High(ArrString) do
      begin
        JSONArray :=  JSONObject.Get(ArrString[i]).JsonValue as TJSONArray;
        for j := 0 to JSONArray.Size-1 do
          begin
            if j = 0 then  Memo1.Lines.Add(ArrString[i]+':');
            Memo1.Lines.Add(TJSONString(TJSONArray(JSONArray.Get(j)).Get(0)).Value+ ' ' +TJSONNumber(TJSONArray(JSONArray.Get(j)).Get(1)).ToString);
          end;
      end;
```

Comment: When iterating the innermost arrays, `Get(1)` does not return a `TJSONString`, it returns a `TJSONNumber` instead. You would have detected that error if you had used `as` casts. And you should be using `TJSONArray.Items[]` instead of `TJSONArray.Get()`. And there most certainly is a [`TJSONPair`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONPair) class.

Comment: You right, `Get(1)` return `TJSONNumber`, thank you for prompt. About `TJSONArray.Items[]`, I can be mistaken, but after XE2 `Items` was replased by `Get`. There are no `Item` in `TJSONArray` in XE5 which I use.

Comment: you are right. `TJSONArray.Items` was added in XE6, when the JSON classes were moved to the new `System.JSON` unit. "*Warning: `Get` is deprecated. Please use `Items`.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to ditch the inbuilt JSON classes, and instead use the excellent [SuperObject](https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject) classes from Henry Gourvest. They've been around longer, are better tested, more powerful, and easier to use.

With those, your code would become:

```
procedure ParseJSON(const JSONString: string);
  const ArrString: array of string = ['asks', 'bids'];
  var JSON, Element: ISuperObject;
      CurrentString: string;
begin
  JSON := SO(JSONString);
  for CurrentString in ArrString do
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(CurrentString + ':');
    for Element in JSON[CurrentString] do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Element.AsArray.S[0] + ' ' + Element.AsArray.D[1].ToString);
  end;
end;
```